# I cannot stream through network using vlc

Tags: networking, stream, video-streaming, vlc

I can't stream a video over network using vlc. When I look logfile I see these lines
What is the problem and how can I solve it? My operating system is windows 10 64 bit. Also I need to make a script to stream a video over network with vlc. I could not find any helpful document about this. Can somebody help me about this issue?

```
main debug: toggling resume
main debug: auto hiding mouse cursor
main debug: auto hiding mouse cursor
main debug: exiting
main debug: exiting
main debug: no exit handler
main debug: removing all interfaces
main debug: removing module "qt"
main debug: deactivating the playlist
main debug: incoming request - stopping current input
main debug: killing decoder fourcc `h264'
main debug: removing module "h264"
main debug: incoming request - stopping current input
main debug: removing a sout input (sout_input: 0000026d28625c20)
main debug: incoming request - stopping current input
main debug: killing decoder fourcc `h264'
main debug: removing module "avcodec"
main debug: incoming request - stopping current input
main debug: saving a free vout
main debug: incoming request - stopping current input
main debug: reusing provided vout
main debug: incoming request - stopping current input
mux_ts debug: removing input pid=100
mux_ts debug: freeing video PID 100
main debug: incoming request - stopping current input
main warning: no more input streams for this mux
main debug: incoming request - stopping current input
main debug: removing module "mp4"
mp4 debug: freeing all memory
main debug: incoming request - stopping current input
main debug: Program doesn't contain anymore ES
main debug: removing module "record"
main debug: incoming request - stopping current input
main debug: removing module "cache_read"
main debug: incoming request - stopping current input
main debug: removing module "filesystem"
main debug: incoming request - stopping current input
main debug: dead input
qt debug: IM: Deleting the input
main debug: nothing to play
main debug: destroying useless sout
main debug: destroying chain... (name=duplicate)
main debug: removing module "duplicate"
duplicate debug: closing a duplication
main debug: destroying chain... (name=display)
main debug: removing module "display"
main debug: destroying useless vout
main debug: removing module "direct3d11"
direct3d11 debug: Direct3D11 resources destroyed
direct3d11 debug: Direct3D11 device adapter closed
direct3d11 error: SetThumbNailClip failed: 0x800706f4
direct3d11 debug: Win32 Vout EventThread terminating
direct3d11 debug: Win32VoutCloseWindow
direct3d11 debug: WinProc WM_DESTROY
main debug: removing module "inhibit"
qt debug: releasing video...
qt debug: Video is not needed anymore
main debug: removing module "freetype"
main debug: removing module "yuvp"
main debug: removing module "swscale"
main debug: destroying chain done
main debug: destroying chain... (name=standard)
main debug: removing module "stream_out_standard"
main debug: removing module "mux_ts"
main debug: removing module "udp"
main debug: destroying chain done
main debug: destroying chain done
main debug: removing module "mmdevice"
qt debug: requesting exit...
qt debug: waiting for UI thread...
qt debug: QApp exec() finished
qt debug: Video is not needed anymore
qt debug: Killing extension dialog provider
qt debug: ExtensionsDialogProvider is quitting...
main debug: removing module "lua"
main debug: removing module "win32"
main debug: removing module "hotkeys"
main debug: removing module "win_msg"
main debug: destroying
main debug: saving media library to file C:\Users\gulbe\AppData\Roaming\vlc\ml.xspf.tmp30208
main debug: looking for playlist export module matching "export-xspf": 4 candidates
main debug: using playlist export module "export"
main debug: removing module "export"
main debug: deleting item `Media Library'
main debug: deleting item `videoOo.mp4'
main debug: deleting item `Playlist'
main debug: removing module "memory"
-- logger module stopped --
-- logger module started --
main: one instance mode ENABLED
```